# Qual o comando que utilizo para colocar parâmetro em uma lista no sql?

Tags: sql

Estava realizando uma prova apareceu uma questão dizendo para criar uma lista em que os valores não fossem maior que 6, não consegui compreender muito bem fazer isso.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, porém não seria apenas fazer um SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE valor <= 6?

Comment: Sim,  isso resolveu meu problema, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o que estão solicitando é que você retorne os registros de uma tabela cujo o valor de um determinado campo não seja maior que 6.

Se for isso teria que fazer assim:

```
select *
from tabela
where campo <= 6
```